# Python: How to force pandas to sort columns in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataset

I have below dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({2002:[None, None, 2, 4, 5],  
                   "Facility":[5, 5, 6, 44, 2], 
                   2003:[None, None, None, 1, 5], 
                   2004 : [ 4,4,3,2,6]})
```

and I need to sort the columns, in order do so I use the following code

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

however it complains with the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I know that error appears since one of col names is str type, but how can I solve this problem?

My favorit answer has the sorted columns as below:

```
'Facility',2002,2003,2004
```

Comment: It's unusual to have column names that are not strings. Is there a reason you need them?

Comment: please try this one to change the type of columnnames `df.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: You want a specific order that logically has no real sorting logic so why not just specify the columns: `df[['Facility', 2002, 2003, 2004]]`?

Comment: Could you use a custom sort? `sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: -1 if isinstance(x, str) else x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

As you already mentioned, your colnames is a combination of String and int therefore the sort is not successful. So, you can do the following to sort the columns

```
df.columns.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup: ensure all values that are supposed to be strings are str, and integers are int**

1) Get a list of the columns:

`my_columns = list(df.columns)`

2) Remove "Facility" from the list:

`my_columns.remove("Facility")`

3) Sort the list of integers:

`my_columns.sort()`

4) Insert facility into the front of the list:

`my_columns.insert(0, "Facility")`

5) Reorder the DataFrame with the newly ordered `my_columns`:

`df = df[my_columns]`

6) Change columns back to all strings with something like:

`df.columns.astype(str)`